# GCM-AEAD support for ubuntu system running linux kernel-3.10

Tags: encryption, linux-kernel, cryptography, aes-gcm

I am trying to implement a AEAD sample code for encryption Using GCM encryption. But I always get invalid argument error while setting the key

```
static int init_aead(void)
    {
        printk("Starting encryption\n");
        struct crypto_aead *tfm = NULL;
        struct aead_request *req;
        struct tcrypt_result tresult;

        struct scatterlist plaintext[1] ;
        struct scatterlist ciphertext[1];
        struct scatterlist gmactext[1];
        unsigned char *plaindata = NULL;
        unsigned char *cipherdata = NULL;
        unsigned char *gmacdata = NULL;

        const u8 *key =  kmalloc(16, GFP_KERNEL);

        char *algo = "rfc4106(gcm(aes))";
        unsigned char *ivp = NULL;
        int ret, i, d;
        unsigned int iv_len;
        unsigned int keylen = 16;

        /* Allocating a cipher handle for AEAD */
        tfm = crypto_alloc_aead(algo, 0, 0);
        init_completion(&tresult.completion);
        if(IS_ERR(tfm)) {
                     pr_err("alg: aead: Failed to load transform for %s: %ld\n", algo,
                            PTR_ERR(tfm));
                return PTR_ERR(tfm);
        }

        /* Allocating request data structure to be used with AEAD data structure */
        req = aead_request_alloc(tfm, GFP_KERNEL);
        if(IS_ERR(req)) {
            pr_err("Couldn't allocate request handle for %s:\n", algo);
            return PTR_ERR(req);
        }

        /* Allocting a callback function to be used , when the request completes */
        aead_request_set_callback(req, CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG, aead_work_done,&tresult);

        crypto_aead_clear_flags(tfm, ~0);

        /* Set key */
        get_random_bytes((void*)key, keylen);

     if((ret = crypto_aead_setkey(tfm, key, 16) != 0)) {
            pr_err("Return value for setkey is %d\n", ret);
            pr_info("key could not be set\n");
                ret = -EAGAIN;
            return ret;
        }

        /* Set authentication tag length */
            if(crypto_aead_setauthsize(tfm, 16)) {
            pr_info("Tag size could not be authenticated\n");
                ret = -EAGAIN;
            return ret;
        }

        /* Set IV size */
        iv_len = crypto_aead_ivsize(tfm);
        if (!(iv_len)){
            pr_info("IV size could not be authenticated\n");
                     ret = -EAGAIN;
                     return ret;
             }


        plaindata  = kmalloc(16, GFP_KERNEL);
        cipherdata = kmalloc(16, GFP_KERNEL);
        gmacdata   = kmalloc(16, GFP_KERNEL);
        ivp        = kmalloc(iv_len, GFP_KERNEL);

        if(!plaindata || !cipherdata || !gmacdata || !ivp) {
            printk("Memory not availaible\n");
            ret = -ENOMEM;
            return ret;
        }
        for (i = 0, d = 0; i < 16; i++, d++)
            plaindata[i] = d;

        memset(cipherdata, 0, 16);
        memset(gmacdata, 0, 16);

        for (i = 0,d=0xa8; i < 16; i++, d++)
            ivp[i] = d;

        sg_init_one(&plaintext[0], plaindata, 16);
        sg_init_one(&ciphertext[0], cipherdata, 16);
        sg_init_one(&gmactext[0], gmacdata, 128);
        aead_request_set_crypt(req, plaintext, ciphertext, 16, ivp);
        aead_request_set_assoc(req, gmactext, 16);

        ret = crypto_aead_encrypt(req);

        if (ret)
            printk("cipher call returns %d \n", ret);
        else
            printk("Failure \n");
        return 0;
     }

     module_init(init_aead);
     module_exit(exit_aead);
     MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
     MODULE_DESCRIPTION("My code for aead encryption test");
     }
```

On inserting the module I get following output

> Starting encryption
>   Return value for setkey is -22
>   key could not be set

According to AEAD specification aead uses aes-128 for encryption hence the block size should be 128 bit .

But my system shows only 1 Byte block size support for AEAD

```
name         : rfc4106(gcm(aes))
driver       : rfc4106-gcm-aesni
module       : aesni_intel
priority     : 400
refcnt       : 1
selftest     : passed
type         : nivaead
async        : yes
blocksize    : 1
ivsize       : 8
maxauthsize  : 16
geniv        : seqiv
```

Does the invalid argument error is thrown becuase of the block size. If so , what shall I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block size of AES is indeed always 128 bit. The block size of GCM is a different matter though. GCM (Galois-Counter Mode) is - as the name suggests - build on top of the CTR (Counter) mode of operation, sometimes also called the SIC (Segmented Integer Counter) mode of operation. This turns AES into a stream cipher. Stream ciphers - by definition - have a block size of one byte (or, more precisely, one bit, but bit level operations are usually not supported by API's).

Block size however has little to do with the key size displayed in the call, and the argument does seem to require bytes instead of bits (in which key lengths are usually defined).

The size of the IV should be 12 bytes (the default). Otherwise additional calculations may be needed by the GCM implementation (if those exist at all).

Comment: Could you check if the comments above helps you solve the issue?

Comment: Thanx for your help . I have one more doubt. Does the blocksize :1   specifies the length of  input block size  or the  output block size? . According to crypto_aead_setkey definition in latest mainline kernel ."""When providing a 16 byte key for an AES cipher handle, AES-128 is performed""" [http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/crypto/aead.c#L52].  In case the block size is the input datasize i.e 1 byte and we provide 16 byte key , will it work? If not so what could be the reason I am getting a -EINVAL error eror?

Comment: The block size and key size are not directly related to one another. Input and output block size are always the same though. It depends on the implementation how many bytes are handled in time though; unfortunately I've got ony 30 minutes left to eat and prepare my kayak :)

Comment: Thank you once again :) . Can you point me what am I doing wrong here and what should I do to make  it work?

Answer (score 0):

For Aes GCM RFC 4106 the key must be 20 bytes. I don't known yet why. I've looked into ipsec source code to see how the encryption is made there.